# Парсинг hh.ru с помощью python

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0, 50):
    hh_parser = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=маркетинг&page=' + str(i)).json()
    for j in hh_parser['items']:
        print(j['name'])
jobsList = ["Руководитель+маркетинг", 'Интернет+маркетолог', 'Директор+маркетинга']
for job in jobsList:    
    for i in range(0, 3):
        hh_parser = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=' + job + '&page=' + str(i)).json()
        for j in hh_parser['items']:
            print(j['name'], '-', j['salary'])
with open('hh.csv', 'w') as f:
    for job in jobsList:    
        for i in range(0, 3):
            hh_parser = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=' + job + '&page=' + str(i)).json()
            for j in hh_parser['items']:
                f.write(j['employer']['name'])
                f.write('\t')
                try:
                    f.write(j['salary']['from'])
                except:
                    f.write('ЗП не указано')
                f.write('\t')
                try:
                    f.write(j['snippet']['requirements'])
                except:
                    f.write('No req')
                f.write('\t')
                f.write(job)
                f.write('\n')
```

> Почему csv файл не сохраняет доход f.write(j['salary']['from']) и этот критерий f.write(j['salary']['from']) а только пишет ЗП не указано и No req ?

Comment: наверное, нужно поставить нормальный обработчик ошибок и `j['salary']['from']` привести к строке

Comment: @nörbörnën можете подсказать что значит "поставить нормальный обработчик ошибок"?

Comment: как минимум в некоторых вакансиях зарплата действительно не указана